# Identifying a session hijacking attack

Tags: authentication, cookies, session-management

I understand session hijacking has been a widespread attack vector in the past months.

If an attacker steals a user’s session cookies, they can bypass 2FA and login/password.

If this is the case, how can the victim identify they’ve been session hijacked?

I suspect I’ve been a victim of such an attack, but I do not see any unreasonable, suspicious IPs in the log history. The User-Agent strings also appear to be coming from my devices/browsers. How well can these be spoofed? What can I look out for?

Comment: The things to look for are IPs and actions that you did not take. Why do you think your session has been hijacked? and to what?

Comment: I’ve had suspicious activity on 3 platforms: Facebook, Twitter, and Snapchat. 

1) Facebook: tried logging in one day and was asked to verify my account (never happened before) . 2) Twitter: sessions showing up as “Web” despite only ever logging in on my phone. 3) Snapchat: logged out of session randomly. Snap has a one-device only policy.

Comment: These sites have anti-hijacking. I doubt your sessions have been hijacked. Your accounts may be compromised, but not your sessions...

Comment: I had never been logged out of a Snap session before. If they’d compromised my account via password with some other IP or device, it would’ve been reflected in the logs, right? Is there any other reason why my session would’ve ended? —Furthermore, I’m not so sure that is true for FB, currently. There have been several reported instances of bypassing 2FA and login.

Comment: Session hijacking is a very specific attack. It seems like you are jumping to this conclusion as a catch-all for account compromise. I'm saying that you need to expand your consideration of the possibilities.

Comment: I am particularly concerned about the Snap situation because the accounts there can stay logged in indefinitely. Unless someone else is accessing the account, it stays logged in. I cannot think of a situation where my session would log out at such a random time. I downloaded my data but I don’t see any suspicious IPs, devices, or user agent strings. I am now wondering how possible is it that the user agent string was spoofed to look as if it is coming from my account.

Comment: User agent strings don't do that. Again, I think you're grasping at bits that you don't quite fully understand. I think you are overreacting.

Comment: That’s why I’m here. To better understand.

Comment: But what you've done is jump to conclusions and asked us to confirm these wild theories. That's not asking for understanding. That's creating arbitrary strawmen.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on a faulty premise.

Comment: That wasn’t my intention. My research from credible websites and other supposed cybersecurity “specialists” indicated these can be spoofed. I came here to confirm and learn how/if that was really possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I answer your questions, some general remarks:

> If an attacker steals a user’s session cookies [...]

It is not mandatory for session tokens to be exchanged exclusively as cookies. You can have [client side session](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_(computer_science)#Client-side_web_sessions) tokens (e.g. [JWT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token)) that are communicated between the two parties (client-server) using a different header (e.g. [`Authorization`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Client_side))

> how can the victim identify they’ve been session hijacked?

It it generally very difficult to prove that a session hijack has taken place.

A [session hijack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking) is difficult to be detected as an action, because it basically means that an attacker copies your session token and uses it in order to impersonate you and use the target system with your privileges. Obviously, it's very difficult (if not impossible) to know whether someone has copied your session token<sup>1</sup>.

However, it's important to remember that a session hijack (as every attack) leaves traces of actions on the target system. As such, you can look for [indicators of compromise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_of_compromise) in order to conclude that someone has been using your account on the target system; for example, you can look for configuration changes and/or other actions that you haven't done, which is a strong indication that someone else has done them for you.

Having said that, indicators of compromise do not indicate *how* the attacker has gained access to your system; i.e. it does not mean that if you identify an intrusion, that this intrusion took place because of a session hijack. In order to narrow down the [attack vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attack_vector) to this, you need to inspect the logs from the target system and look for entries that point to a session hijack (e.g. in the case where the target system logs the IP of each request origin, you may see sudden changes of IPs on requests within the same session - some systems detect this automatically and expire all related sessions immediately).

Now, to answer your specific questions, based on the details you provide in your question and your comments ([this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/272116/identifying-a-session-hijacking-attack#comment566295_272116) and [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/272116/identifying-a-session-hijacking-attack#comment566297_272116)): it is my understanding that [you've already decided](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias) that someone's hijacking you, but - honestly - the behaviour you're describing seems legit<sup>2</sup>. Because account compromises are frequent, sites try to shorten an attacker's [window of opportunity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_of_opportunity) by re-confirming your credentials at intervals and/or ways that may seem suspicious to you. The sites you mention are reputable ones, with many users throughout the world - it is expected that they have counter-measures in place that defend against the majority of attacks, hijacking included.

However, if we were to accept that there's indeed a problem and someone's using your accounts, I would be inclined to believe that this someone has your credentials at hand, rather than is stealing your sessions (keep in mind that session hijacking needs to take place every time that you've refreshed your session token, e.g. you've logged out and re-logged in to a site - this, *for each site*). So, if this is the case, I would suspect that the devices (from which you connect to your accounts) are compromised and that malware has been installed to steal your credentials (e.g. a [keylogger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystroke_logging)). Malware may also allow for session hijacking - but why would you want to do this and not just use the credentials, which is easier anyway?

---

<sup>1</sup> you can put some measures that help identify such things, e.g. a counter in your token, that changes with every request, so that [replay attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack) are detected. However, I'm not sure whether it's widely adopted for sessions

<sup>2</sup> e.g. for your snap example, maybe your session token eventually expired - you can verify this if there's no activity with your account after you got "kicked out" of your connection. If there is, then you should also see *different IPs* logged server side (given the one-device policy) unless the other device that uses your account comes from the same LAN as your main device (thus, being behind the same NAT server, hence having the same IP)

Comment: Thanks for your response. The Snap situation is very rare. It usually never logs out after 24 hours of inactivity unless someone else is logged into the account. It can stay logged in indefinitely. You’re saying there’s a chance the cookie expired after a year or two or something? I had sensitive information there so you can imagine I am extremely worried. I downloaded my data and haven’t seen any suspicious devices, though. Is that a good sign?

Comment: I'm not sure about the specifics of Snap, but from my experience a year or two without having to re-verify your id is too long. Anyway, here's some [info](https://help.snapchat.com/hc/en-us/articles/7012305621908-My-account-is-compromised) from Snap about how to keep your account safe. I understand your worries, but since you don't have any indicators of compromise then either you're targeted by a *very* skilled attacker or you're overreacting. In general, keep an eye for suspicious activity, try to figure out who would want to harm you and why (motives + resources) and go from there.